# How can I add an additional email address to the "From" dropdown in Outlook 2016?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016, hotmail

I have a Hotmail account that I use in (desktop) Outlook 2016. As well as the primary address it has several [aliases](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/12407/microsoft-account-manage-aliases) and all except one of these aliases can be selected with the `From` button on new emails as the sender address. The most recent alias (which, if it matters, is an @outlook.com address) is not showing here, although I can type it in manually and mail is successfully sent.

I don't recall having done anything to get the other aliases to show up and I can't find anything that will add it to the list. How do I do this?

I've restarted Outlook (and the computer) several times and looked through the Account and general Outlook options, all to no avail, as well as sending from the address by manually entering it, as I said.

---

#### EDIT

According to [howto-outlook.com](https://www.howto-outlook.com/faq/aliases.htm), the alias should show up automatically in Outlook 2016's `From` drop-down: see `How can I choose which alias to send out with?` -> `Method 3: From field (Outlook.com)`. If I was using an earlier version of Outlook, it should show up once I'd used it manually. As neither is working, there must be a bug somewhere and so I suppose this question becomes, "Is there a workaround?", i.e. something to kickstart an update or force a recreation of the "From" list.

I suspect an answer may be remove the account and reload it. Theoretically this should be pain free, but if anyone can suggest a potentially less destructive option, I'd like to hear it first!

Comment: Does this link help? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/i-can-t-see-my-outlook-com-email-in-outlook-2016-or-outlook-2013-cda1751d-9503-40bf-bf76-e79454ac5eb3

Comment: @spikey_richie Thanks for the suggestion, but I did this at the time that article was published. If I remember correctly, it was when Microsoft email accounts migrated to an Exchange backend. It _is_ possible that deleting and reconnecting would solve my problem, but I was hoping there was a less drastic solution - deleting my local account and the potential trouble it could cause is my last resort option!

Comment: I’m surprised an aliases show up. Outlook does not display aliases of exchange based email accounts. There is a “paid” product out there that is a plug-in to Outlook and adds the aliases to Outlook. However, in essence, all it does is add the alias as its own account in Outlook using SNTP for mail submission. It’s a glaring hole in Outlook, but that’s the way it is for now.

Comment: @Appleoddity Now you're worrying me that if I remove the account and reconnect to it, all my other aliases will disappear!

Comment: Not likely. Apparently we don’t have enough details to understand why it would show up or not. I just know that Outlook typically does not list aliases in the From drop down. The solution is to use a third party plugin or create smtp accounts for the aliases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More than 2 years later(!), I did, in fact, delete the account from Outlook and reconnect to it. The alias has appeared in the drop-down and I can successfully send from it. Probably should have done so sooner!

(@Appleoddity: none of my other aliases vanished!)